# Generate data for clustering

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, random-forest, data-generation

I want to test my Random Forest clustering with some artificial data. I wanted to generate dataset with strong dependability and some noise.

I have 2 attributes, A1 and A2 (both binary). The class is calculated as: A1 xor A2. I added few noisy binary attributes.

For example, we have:

```
A1   A2   noise | class
0    0     ...  | 0
0    1     ...  | 1
1    0     ...  | 1
1    1     ...  | 0
 ...       ...  | ...
```

In clustering we don't have a class, so for random forest clustering we take original data and transform it. We mark all existing cases with class 1 and add synthetic data marked with class 2. Synthetic data is built by random sampling from all values for some attribute.

This is what we get:

```
A1   A2   noise | class
0    0     ...  | 1
0    1     ...  | 1
1    0     ...  | 1
1    1     ...  | 1
       .....
------------------------- 
0    0     ...  | 2
0    0     ...  | 2
1    1     ...  | 2
0    1     ...  | 2
       .....
```

Upper part is original data (as above) marked with class 1. Under the line is random sampled synthetic data marked with class 2. Random Forest tries to find some structure that distinguishes class 1 from 2 (real data from random data). Problem is, XOR without a class tells us nothing and there is nothing to learn here.

Finally, my question:
How to generate data for random forest clustering, with non-dependent, mildly-dependent or strong-dependent attributes?